# Swift walking distance calculated

Tags: swift, swift3, distance, core-location, pedometer

I want to calculate walking distance after click button.I used CMPedometer for application but I don't want to use CMPedometer. I will make it with location info. I used core location framework but I don't trust this variable.I share with you mine code

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate  {

    var backgroundTaskIdentifier: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //locationManager.delegate = self
        if NSString(string:UIDevice.current.systemVersion).doubleValue > 8 {
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        }
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest

        backgroundTaskIdentifier = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: {
            UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTaskIdentifier!)
        })

        var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

    func update() {
        var speed: CLLocationSpeed = CLLocationSpeed()
        speed = locationManager.location!.speed
        print(String(format: "%.0f km/h", speed * 3.6))
        latitute.text = String(format: "%.0f km/h", speed * 3.6)
    }

    @IBAction func resetDistance(_ sender: Any) {
        startLocation = nil
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        var speed: CLLocationSpeed = CLLocationSpeed()
        speed = (locationManager.location?.speed)!

        latitute.text =  String(format: "%.0f km/h", speed * 3.6)
        print(speed);
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status != CLAuthorizationStatus.denied{
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }






    @IBOutlet weak var latitute: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var longitude: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var horizontalAccuracy: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var altitude: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var verticalAccuracy: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var distance: UILabel!

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var startLocation: CLLocation!
}

class Utility {

    class func convertCLLocationDistanceToMiles ( targetDistance : CLLocationDistance?) -> CLLocationDistance {
        var targetDistance = targetDistance
        targetDistance =  targetDistance!*0.00062137
        return targetDistance!
    }
    class func convertCLLocationDistanceToKiloMeters ( targetDistance : CLLocationDistance?) -> CLLocationDistance {
        var targetDistance = targetDistance
        targetDistance =  targetDistance!/1000
        return targetDistance!
    }

}
```

Please can you check it this code correctly working.
**I hope help with me**

Comment: Why don't you test it?

Comment: UIDevice.current.systemVersion returns the system version, not a Double. What if the version is something like 10.0.1?

Comment: I did test. I put the phone on the desk but the road I'm getting is growing. :( @dasdom